# Why doesn't SP remember my column sort settings?

Tags: document-library, list-view, folder, file, sorting

I have a SP files site, the folders of which are labelled 01_label 1, 02_label 2 etc. which I want to have sorted in order of the first two characters.

Instead, every time I open it, even after changing it back to Sort<A-Z it is sorted Z-A so 07_label 7 is at the top.

This also happens with another files site I have whereby the first characters are the date, backwards, in order to show the newest at the top, but it too keeps defaulting to the newest is on the bottom of the list.  This is frustrating and causes me unnecessary sorting or scrolling to find the folder I need.

Please can anyone advise why this is happening and what I can do about it?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have saved the default library view with the sorting. So, try this:

1. Go to SharePoint document library where files are saved.
2. Click on **Switch view options** at the top & select **Edit current view**. If you are not using SharePoint online, go to library settings & then select the default library view at the bottom.

   [image]
3. Set the sorting settings as per your requirement like:

   [image]
4. Click on **OK** at the bottom of view settings page.
5. Next time you open the document library, it will remember the sorting settings you applied in above steps.